How to use VSCode to a container running on a SLURM cluster?
I'm trying to connect to a container in a slurm cluster.
I am using srun --container-image <IMG> to start a container. This container gets sent to a compute node which I am able to control/identify. Also I'm not able to modify the container to install a sshd-server.
I'm able to use the remote-ssh extension in VSCode to connect to this node.
However, the Dev Containers extension is not able to detect any running containers on this compute node. The Docker extension seems to suggest that docker is not running on the compute node which makes sense as I believe slurm is using enroot?

You might benefit from checking this gist: https://gist.github.com/malteos/5fe791fe10bb55028a02952d5f394bb3
